# Qpushbutton in custom QlistWidgetItem doesn't respond when running on embedded device

Tags: pyqt5, embedded-linux

I'm quite new to pyqt5 and applications on embedded devices, and was hoping someone may have any tips or suggestions on the problems I'm facing.

I am working with a pyqt5 appliaction where the widget contains a QListWidget and two buttons. I have made a seperate widget that I use as a customized QListWidgetItem. The customized QListWidgetItem contains a textfield and a QPushButton.
Everything works perfectly on Ubuntu on my computer, but when I deploy and run the app on an embedded device, the buttons in the customized QListWidgetItem no longer responds. The "normal" buttons, that are not in the customized QListWidgetItem, still works normally.

I can't find a reason or fixes for this, and am quite stuck..

Here's my code, *very* simplified:

***Edit!*** After some feedback I've created a smaller representation of the app/problem, which hopefully can make it easier to debug.
I no longer use pyqtSignal between the classes, only connected the buttons to different functions directly.
In this case, both the printing and color changing will happen if the buttons respond correctly.

python file:

```
import sys
from CustomListItem import Ui_custom_list_widget
from CollectorWidget import Ui_collector_widget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QListWidgetItem, QApplication, QStackedWidget, QMainWindow

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    stack = QStackedWidget()
    collector = CollectorWidget()
    stack.addWidget(collector)
    stack.setCurrentWidget(collector)
    stack.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


class CollectorWidget(Ui_collector_widget, QWidget):
    temp_list_items = []

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CollectorWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.create_item_button.clicked.connect(self.create_item_clicked)
        self.another_button.clicked.connect(lambda: print("this one works"))
        

    def create_item_clicked(self):
        self.listItem = QListWidgetItem()
        self.item = CustomListItem()
        self.item.custom_item_button.clicked.connect(self.test_signal)        
        self.qlistwidget_list.addItem(self.listItem)
        self.qlistwidget_list.setItemWidget(self.listItem, self.item)
        self.temp_list_items.append((self.listItem, self.item))
        
    def test_signal(self):
        print("--------------IT'S WORKING!--------------------------")


class CustomListItem(Ui_custom_list_widget, QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.item_name.setText("testing testing")
        self.custom_item_button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def setItemText(self, text):
        self.item_name.setText(text)

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.item_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ui files (collector):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'CollectorWidget.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_collector_widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, collector_widget):
        collector_widget.setObjectName("collector_widget")
        collector_widget.resize(625, 514)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(collector_widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.qlistwidget_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(collector_widget)
        self.qlistwidget_list.setObjectName("qlistwidget_list")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.qlistwidget_list)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.create_item_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(collector_widget)
        self.create_item_button.setObjectName("create_item_button")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.create_item_button)
        self.another_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(collector_widget)
        self.another_button.setObjectName("another_button")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.another_button)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(collector_widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(collector_widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, collector_widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        collector_widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("collector_widget", "Form"))
        self.create_item_button.setText(_translate("collector_widget", "Create"))
        self.another_button.setText(_translate("collector_widget", "Just a button"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    collector_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_collector_widget()
    ui.setupUi(collector_widget)
    collector_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ui files (custom_list_item):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'CustomListItem.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_custom_list_widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, custom_list_widget):
        custom_list_widget.setObjectName("custom_list_widget")
        custom_list_widget.resize(608, 40)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(custom_list_widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.item_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(custom_list_widget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.item_name.setFont(font)
        self.item_name.setStyleSheet("")
        self.item_name.setWordWrap(True)
        self.item_name.setObjectName("item_name")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.item_name)
        self.custom_item_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(custom_list_widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.custom_item_button.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.custom_item_button.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.custom_item_button.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(20, 20))
        self.custom_item_button.setStyleSheet("")
        self.custom_item_button.setText("")
        self.custom_item_button.setObjectName("custom_item_button")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.custom_item_button)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)

        self.retranslateUi(custom_list_widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(custom_list_widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, custom_list_widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        custom_list_widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("custom_list_widget", "Form"))
        self.item_name.setText(_translate("custom_list_widget", "TextLabel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    custom_list_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_custom_list_widget()
    ui.setupUi(custom_list_widget)
    custom_list_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Picture of app:

[image]

Comment: I can spot a few conceptual issues with that code (starting from the fact that you're emitting a signal from another object). That said, please provide a [mre] (remember, it has to be *both* minimal *and* reproducible).

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to make a smaller working version now :)

Comment: At this point I'm actually not sure if the issue lies in the app, or the embedded device itself. I'm using a core9x (I'm not the one setting up this device, so my knowledge here is very limited). I know that Qt5 no longer has its own window system (QWS), so it's currently using a Linux Framebuffer via a Qt5 LinuxFB plugin(https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/embedded-linux.html).

Comment: I cannot test in that kind of environment, so I'm just making some guess. It's possible that there is some issue with the focus (which is quite complex for index widgets). Try adding `self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)` to the `__init__` of `CustomListItem`. Be aware that while using index widgets is normally perfectly fine, the general (and more appropriate) approach is to use a custom item delegate.